# GAE Managed VM always unhealthy restarting

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

We're using a Managed VM instance inside Google App Engine. Until today it all went well and running, but in the last 12 hours or so the health checks are ALWAYS failing, which triggers a new VM restart every 10 minutes or so. It's worth mentioning that the image is the same, e.g. no changes have been done to the docker image since three days ago until now.

Any solution to this? Health checks are not handled explicitly by the module. The GAE admin console shows that the latest health check returns a 502 code instead of a 200.

This is really bad because after each restart the IP will also change, the logs get flooded with health fail errors, and ultimately the instance is unusable (it is running a MQTT broker so it needs to be up forever).

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem. Restarts every 10 minutes. It was started after activating SSL and automatic redirects to https url.

Solution was to deactivate https to App Engine reserved urls: /_ah/* . It works on Java 8 compat runtime.